# Printing Identity ("I") matrix in c

Tags: arrays, c, matrix

I'm trying to print out the identity matrix in a square matrix array.

This is my current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int n = 50;
    int i,j = 0;
    int a[n][n];

    for (i=0; i<n; i++){
        for (j=0; j<n; j++){
            if (a[i] == a[j]){
                printf("1");
            } else {
                printf("0");
            }
        }
    }
    printf("/n");
    return 0;
}
```

My macOS terminal doesn't tell me there are any syntax errors and compiles correctly. But when I run the executable I get nothing printed out.

Are there any errors in my code?

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: You never initialized the array `a` so it contains garbage.  On the other hand you also don't need it at all.  The test `if (a[i] == a[j])` should simply be `if (i == j)`.

Comment: Also, think about where your printf of a newline should go.  (And newline in C is `\n`, not `/n`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments. Can you help me out telling me how to initialize my array *a*

Comment: Eye? I think you mean `I`...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, identity matrix, in numpy there is a function that is called eye and it prints out the identity matrix...

Comment: @canaCosmic well, it is a pun on `I`, but it is identity matrix only in its default settings

Comment: How do you execute the program? Is it in a window which closes before you can see the output? This is the explanation for many "I have no output" questions.

Comment: You might have to output a newline or flush the output to see something. Are you sure that the last two letters you want ot output are a slash and a "n"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The posted code is accessing `a` before initializing it.  As was pointed out, if it just wants to print an identity matrix (without actually creating it), the test `a[i] == a[j]` can simply be replaced with `i == j`.

If you instead want to actually initialize `a`, and then print it, you can do it as follows.  First, to initialize it, you can do:

```
for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<n; j++) {
        a[i][j] = i == j;
    }
}
```

The expression `i == j` evaluates to `1` if `i` and `j` are equal, and `0` otherwise, so this will create an identify matrix with `1` on the main diagonal and `0` elsewhere.

After initializing it, you can change it, use it, print it, etc.  To print it, you can do:

```
for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<n; j++) {
        printf(" %d", a[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

This prints a space before each element (as a separator), and ends each row with a newline.  Depending on your needs, you could change this to use a fixed width for each element, etc.  It really depends on what values you're dealing with and how you want it to look when printed.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has problems which will cause it to not output what you want.
The fact that you do not see ANY output however has two possible explanations.

- you execute in a window which closes before you were able to perceive the output; execute from an already open command prompt to see output, because then you will have enough time
- flush output or add outputting a newline at the end; you currently don't and instead output a slash and an "n", things would be different when using the special newline character, as in `"\n"`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int i,j,a[100][100],n=5;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
 for(j=0;j<n;j++)
 {
   if(i=j)
{
    printf("1\t");
}
else
{
printf("0\t");
}
}
}
return 0;
}
```

The condition for printing is not a[i]=a[j] but it has to be i=j.

Comment: No. That is not a condition. In your explanation it does not hurt but in the code it is plain wrong. (As a comparativly minor issue: your indentation if distractingly inconsistent.)

Comment: Urja, please consider [edit]ing your answer to improve it.

Comment: How many lines of output do you expect from this code? Shouldn't a matrix have more than one?

Comment: You probably mean `i == j`.

Comment: Also the reason behind initializing the array with 100 is nothing special you can randomly initialize with any number.